# Jquery Cookie lib for Bootstrap modal: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token ILLEGAL

Tags: jquery, cookies, modal-dialog

I'm trying to include a bootstrap modal and only have it appear every 7 days via jquery.cookie library. When I load the page and view the errors in console, I get the following:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token ILLEGAL
```

Here I grab the script:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

Then I initiate the modal using the cookie function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($.cookie(‘pop’) == null) {
        $(‘#myModal’).modal(‘show’);
        $.cookie(‘pop’, ’7′);
    }
});
</script>
```

Is something wrong with my syntax? As far as I can tell everything is correct, I'm calling the latest jquery lib first in the header, then the cookie lib, then calling the jquery cookie function much later, near the footer (so I'm assuming it's not caused by a delay in the http request).

Here is the site in question: http://goo.gl/12ZvJP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got "smart quotes" in your code. They need to be plain old ASCII single-quote characters.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($.cookie('pop') == null) {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $.cookie('pop', '7');
    }
});
```

Don't edit source code in Word or any other word processor, or if you can't resist, make sure you turn smart quotes off.